# Template filter error: Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: blocks, magento2.3.1

I am facing following exception

> Template filter error: Type Error occurred when creating object

I am getting this exception when I am injecting block `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` in my custom block `\Anshu\CustomModule\Block\Custom`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Anshu\CustomModule\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Anshu\Custom\Helper\ProductCollection;

class Custom extends Template
{
    private $listProduct;

    private $productCollection;

    private $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        ListProduct $listProduct,
        ProductCollection $productCollection,
        Session $customerSession,
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->listProduct = $listProduct;
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function getProducts()
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollection->getProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', 1);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function getCustomerGroupId() :int
    {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
    }

    public function getPrice($product) :string
    {
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
        if (!$priceRender) {
            $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                Render::class,
                'product.price.render.default',
                ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
            );
        }

        $price = '';
        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render(
                FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                $product,
                [
                    'display_minimal_price'  => true,
                    'use_link_for_as_low_as' => true,
                    'zone' => Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST
                ]
            );
        }

        return $price;
    }

    public function getAddToCartPostParams($product) :array
    {
        return $this->listProduct->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
    }
}
```

Let me know if anyone aware of this type of issue, what is causing this issue and how this can be fixed

Comment: please share the code which you have try.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I have added the code for my custom block class

Comment: try to put this line into last into your constructor. parent::__construct($context, $data);

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Tried, not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was because of some third party extension that has overwritten the block using preference in di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="ThirdParty\CustomExtension\Block\Product\ListProduct"/>
```

So, to fix the issue I have changed the class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` to `ThirdParty\CustomExtension\Block\Product\ListProduct` in my custom block `Anshu\CustomModule\Block\Custom`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link: It may help you
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22773

Answer (score 0):

Any external class used in your class and not defined in the DI or not defined can also cause this type of error.

So make sure you have defined your classes properly.